# Tracert getting timeout on second packet consistenly

Tags: routing, vpn, dns, traceroute

I'm on a vpn and tracing to virtualmachines that live in the VPN Server.
I've been experiencing slow queries, when they should be fast.
below is what the trace is returning.

I'm curious as to why the timeout always on the second packet.

```
>tracert MyDevSite.com

Tracing route to devlb.MyDevSite.com [192.168.1.80]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1   187 ms     *      102 ms  VPN Server[192.168.1.146]
  2   122 ms    81 ms    78 ms  LoadBalancer[192.168.1.80]

Trace complete.

>tracert 192.168.1.12

Tracing route to SQLServer [192.168.1.12]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1   115 ms     *       84 ms  VPN Server[192.168.1.146]
  2    69 ms    69 ms    74 ms  SQLServer [192.168.1.12]

Trace complete.
```

What other information would be useful to debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're performing a traceroute, what you're really doing is triggering each router in the path to send you some 'TTL Expired' packets which will reveal the router's presence.  The reason you seem to always loose that second packet is because many systems will rate-limit the number of TTL Expired that they generate in a particular time frame.  If you could increase the wait time between queries, it would probably respond to each one.  If you could decrease the timeout of a failure, that router would probably miss even more responses.  This is not because the router is failing in any way, but it's choosing to rate limit its responses to you.